# how to execute a background.js function when an event is fired in the current tab (chrome extension)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

when i run the following code i get resetTime is not defined , i tried passing the function as an argument bu that did not work, am i supposed to write new logic to reset the time inside **"chrome.scripting.executeScript"** :

```
let time = 0;

function resetTime() {
  time = 0;
  chrome.storage.sync.set({ time: time });
  console.log("Timer reset");
}

setInterval(() => {
  chrome.storage.sync.get(["time"], (result) => {
    console.log("Current time: " + result.time);
  });
}, 1000);

chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener((activeInfo) => {
  chrome.tabs.get(activeInfo.tabId, (tab) => {
    chrome.scripting.executeScript({
      target: { tabId: activeInfo.tabId },
      function: (resetTime) => {
        document.addEventListener("mousemove", (e) => {
          resetTime();
        });

        document.addEventListener("mousedown", (e) => {
          resetTime();
        });
      },
      args: [resetTime],
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code doesn't seem to do anything (`time` will always be `0`). In any case, if you want to communicate with the background service worker from a content script, you'll have to use one of the methods described [here](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/develop/concepts/messaging).

Also, since the change to manifest version 3, using `setInterval` in the background service worker is not recommended, instead of that, you should use the [`chrome.alarms`](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/api/alarms) API.

Because your code doesn't seem to do anything, I will just add an example of how you could set an alarm from a content script.

```
chrome.alarms.onAlarm.addListener(async () => {
  const values = await chrome.storage.get('time');
  const time = ++values.time;
  console.log(time);
  await chrome.storage.set({ time });
});

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((sender, request, sendResponse) => {
  if (request.cmd === 'resetTimer') {
    chrome.storage.set({ time: 0 });
    chrome.alarms.create({ name: 'interval', delayInMinutes: 1, periodInMinutes: 1 });
  }
});

chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener((activeInfo) => {
  chrome.tabs.get(activeInfo.tabId, (tab) => {
    chrome.scripting.executeScript({
      target: { tabId: activeInfo.tabId },
      function: () => {
        function resetTimer() {
           chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ cmd: 'resetTimer' });
        }
        document.addEventListener("mousemove", (e) => {
          resetTime();
        });

        document.addEventListener("mousedown", (e) => {
          resetTime();
        });
      },
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Note that this will infinitely add listeners in the web pages after switching back and forth. The simplest solution is to use document.onmousemove and onmousedown instead of addEventListener. There's also no need for chrome.tabs.get, you can directly use activeInfo.tabId.

Comment: @wOxxOm Oh, yes, the listener is for `chrome.tabs.onActivated`. I've just copied the OP's code. To be honest, I'm not sure what he is trying to do. I was just trying to illustrate how you could communicate with the background worker and with what you could replace `setInterval` in manifest V3.